# How to join on a linking table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I've created a stored procedure and in there I'm joining a couple tables:

```
SELECT ...
FROM [Place] AS [P]

JOIN [Timezone] AS [TZ]
     ON [TZ].[TimezoneId] = [P].[TimezoneId]
JOIN [Address] AS [A]
     ON [P].[PlaceId] = [A].[PlaceId]
```

I have a `Category` table that has a one-to-one relationship to the `Place` table and I also have a `SubCategory` table that has a many-to-many relationship with the `Place` table that looks like this (created in C#):

**Place**:

```
public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
public Category Category { get; set; }

public IList<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
```

**SubCategory**:

```
public List<Place> Places { get; set; }
```

What I'm trying to do is use a `@categoryName` filter on that stored procedure that would find a match for either the `Category` table or the `SubCategory` table, can't be both in the sense that the user can only select one filter at a time in this scenario, think of the category as object 1, 2, 3 and subcategory as object 4, 5, 6.

Confusing names without explanation but that would just make the post longer.

However, in the case of the `SubCategory` table, it would need to query the many-to-many relationship between the `Place` table and the `SubCategory` table.

When I created this relationship, using EF Core, it created a linking table `PlaceSubCategory` that I want to use in this case and join it, so that I can then query in such a way (even though it is flawed at the moment):

```
WHERE
    (Category.Name = @categoryName OR SubCategory.Name = @categoryName)
```

And have one single filter that I can run through both the `Category` table and the `SubCategory` table and find a match, and then return the matching result.

However I don't seem to quite get how to do that right and I couldn't really find the information on the web, neither in my book.

Comment: You need to use a Left Outer Join in c# to be able to join items that are not in all three tables (TZ, P, A).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.PlaceID,*
FROM [Place] AS [P]
LEFT [Category] as cat on (P.placeid=cat.placeid)
LEFT [SubCategory] as subcat on (P.placeid=subcat.placeid)
LEFT JOIN [Timezone] AS [TZ]
     ON [TZ].[TimezoneId] = [P].[TimezoneId]
LEFT JOIN [Address] AS [A]
     ON [P].[PlaceId] = [A].[PlaceId]
WHERE (cat.Name = @categoryName OR subcat.Name = @categoryName)
```